# RSS C# to get exchange rates

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

How do I use this RSS to get the exchange rates so I can use it in my app?

http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/frequency/exchange-rates.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357210.aspx). You can use SyndicationFeed.Load() method like this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.rba.gov.au/rss/rss-cb-exchange-rates.xml");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no RDF reader built into the framework which is the format used in the feed exposed by this site so you could use a [third party library](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/).